# ISTQB - Software test automation engineer tutorials and model questions papers

Tags: automated-testing, istqb

I am preparing for ISTQB Test Automation Engineer examination.

I cannot find any tutorials or model question papers.

Please provide some links?

Comment: @trashpanda - maybe you could expand on your comment and make it an answer?

Answer (score 3):

There are questions and answers available [on ISTQB's website](https://www.istqb.org/downloads/category/49-advanced-level-test-automation-engineer-exam-documents.html).

[Looking at their roadmap](https://www.istqb.org/certification-path-root.html), there is no Foundation or Intermediate Automation Engineer exam, so you might want to try searching for terms that include the words "Advanced Level Test Automation Engineer Exam Documents" or something similar.

I also managed to find these [test questions answers](https://www.testingexcellence.com/istqb-quiz/istqb-test-automation-sample-online-exam/) when searching for the above.

Comment: Also, please provide some tutorials links

Comment: Tutorials on what?

Comment: Nice answer but I also don't understand that 'tutorail' ?

Comment: Video links for easy learning and understanding the concepts more clearly.

Here is a [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KzBKACyjH68&list=PLbJF4g421wqnECYEPe0CCAJO9XfWMgJMr) for foundation level.

Likewise, if you find anything for advanced Automation Test Engineer level. Please provide it.

Comment: Dear @BharathQA, ISTQB AL TAE certificate is pretty new one. I work for training provider and we just launched our first TAE training. If you want free stuff, then you need to wait until somebody in community wants to invest their time to create and share it for free.

Answer (score 1):

I have found one more link having questions and answer pdfs

https://astqb.org/resources/

Click on -> Sample Exams

Scroll and look for -> test automation engineer

Answer (score 0):

Happy to help. I have 11 years experience in UFT and selenium. Cleared foundations during 2012. This is my first post in this website.

Have cleared this certification recently by following the steps below:

1. Glanced at the entire syllabus first:
   https://www.istqb.org/downloads/send/48-advanced-level-test-automation-engineer-documents/201-advanced-test-automation-engineer-syllabus-ga-2016.html
2. Discussed with few folks who already cleared in recent days through linkedin-Came to know that we should not trust Dumps since the answers are fake and unreliable.
3. Downloaded entire Q&A by board and practiced them:
   https://www.istqb.org/downloads/send/48-advanced-level-test-automation-engineer-documents/249-istqb-ctal-tae-sample-exam-answers2016.html
4. While choosing face to face or online training,came to know that majority of training institutes don't have trainers with automation experience to teach this certification. Hence I chose a nice online program for detailed preparation:
   https://engineers-hub.teachable.com/p/istqb-advanced-level-test-automation-engineer-professional-training-with-q-a
5. Prepared latest Q&A provided by test takers at teachable(above)
6. Before taking certification, luckily got two new sessions added on test takers interviews in same online course. (Thanks to those people explained about format of exam)
7. Scheduled exam with printed certificate option at isqi:
   https://isqi.org/en/19-istqb-certified-tester-test-automation-engineer.html
8. Appeared on test and cleared with 82 percent.
9. Finally the prestigious certificate of ISTQB advanced test automation engineer arrived with logo sticker all the way from Germany.

Hope you clear the certification just like me. Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Hi Sameer, I could not clear the exam (got just 1 point less than the required limit). I found the questions extremely lengthy because of which I ran short of time at the end. I would like to practice more questions (mainly scenario based) but could not find online. I did two Sample Papers available on ISTQB and ASTQB website but they do not reflect actual questions asked in the exam I feel.